# Handling overflow of horizontal stepper

Tags: flutter

I implemented a very simple horizontal stepper with a few steps. However i get the overflow banner stating that my steps does not fit the view.

**How can I make the bar with the steps scrollable?**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SetupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SetupPageState createState() => _SetupPageState();
}

class _SetupPageState extends State<SetupPage> {

  List<Step> steps = [
    new Step(title: Text('Step 1'), content: new Container()),
    new Step(title: Text('Step 2'), content: new Container()),
    new Step(title: Text('Step 3'), content: new Container()),
    new Step(title: Text('Step 4'), content: new Container()),
    new Step(title: Text('Step 5'), content: new Container()),
    new Step(title: Text('Step 6'), content: new Container()),
    new Step(title: Text('Step 7'), content: new Container()),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Setup'),),
      body: new Stepper(steps: steps, type: StepperType.horizontal, currentStep: 0,),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Without the code for the stepper or at the very least a couple of screenshots we can only guess what's happening here. Please edit your question to add more information.

Comment: That being said, you could probably use a [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

Comment: How did you solved that? Still can't find an answer

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @Jens did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the source code of the Stepper and it does not handle overflow horizontally in its header (the bar with the steps). The `scrollPhysics` property is not even used in _`buildHorizontal`, the method called to build the header when its direction is horizontal.

At time of writing this appears to be completely unsupported. I opened an issue on the flutter github page so maybe it will get fixed.

Comment: Can you please link the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Jens: please try to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/fa_stepper) to custom horizontal stepper, with this [example](https://github.com/dipnv/flutter_stepper)

Comment: Please add a little bit of information on how the package can be used to solve the problem. This will help future readers determine if they should look into it more.

Comment: please visit [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to contribute a good answer.